# Why does normalizedNER for dates in my local stanford corenlp server doesn't display correctly

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have cloned the latest version of stanfordnlp from github.
I'm trying to get proper NER for dates like 1990s, 19th century, etc.

the corenlp demo server displays the dates properly. For eg. 19th century returns NER as 18XX

[image: corenlp demo version]

but on my server 19th century returns NER as 19****19

[image: local version]

Am I using the wrong model or something else. any ideas?
The model that I'm using is 
stanford-english-corenlp-2016-01-10-models.jar
and 
stanford-english-corenlp-models-current.jar

Comment: It looks like I don't have the timex node in my NER tokens at all. Can anyone tell me how i can have the timex node in the output NER tokens. Thank you.

Comment: Found a way to make this happen.
I needed to pass all the jars in the lib directory while starting the server, so my server initiation script was something like  java -mx4g -cp "*:lib/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer