# Why does the Stanford NER demo convert 'this year' to 2017, whereas my CoreNLP server does not?

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have set up a CoreNLP server and am using Stanford NER to extract time periods from sentences.

If I use the online interactive demo at corenlp.run to parse the sentence

> 'Last year something happened.'

[it shows 'DATE' and '2016'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxdB9.png).
However, my own server, set up with the latest release of CoreNLP, [only shows 'DATE'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL9qw.png). What's more, when I use Python Requests to query my server's API with the same sentence, the first two tokens in the response contain the fields `'timex': {'type': 'DATE','tid': 't1', 'altValue': 'THIS P1Y OFFSET P-1Y'}` and `'normalizedNER': 'THIS P1Y OFFSET P-1Y'`.

If I just have to deal with the fact that my output is not as good as the demo's, then where is the Stanford NER or timex3 documentation explaining what `THIS P1Y OFFSET P-1Y` means or describing what other possible responses I might get in the `normalizedNER` field?

Here is the entire API response

```
[
{'word': 'Last', 'after': ' ', 'originalText': 'Last', 'timex': {'type': 'DATE', 'tid': 't1', 'altValue': 'THIS P1Y OFFSET P-1Y'}, 'pos': 'JJ', 'ner': 'DATE', 'lemma': 'last', 'normalizedNER': 'THIS P1Y OFFSET P-1Y', 'before': '', 'index': 1, 'characterOffsetBegin': 0, 'characterOffsetEnd': 4},
{'word': 'year', 'after': ' ', 'originalText': 'year', 'timex': {'type': 'DATE', 'tid': 't1', 'altValue': 'THIS P1Y OFFSET P-1Y'}, 'pos': 'NN', 'ner': 'DATE', 'lemma': 'year', 'normalizedNER': 'THIS P1Y OFFSET P-1Y', 'before': ' ', 'index': 2, 'characterOffsetBegin': 5, 'characterOffsetEnd': 9},
{'word': 'something', 'before': ' ', 'originalText': 'something', 'ner': 'O', 'lemma': 'something', 'after': ' ', 'characterOffsetEnd': 19, 'index': 3, 'characterOffsetBegin': 10, 'pos': 'NN'},
{'word': 'happened', 'before': ' ', 'originalText': 'happened', 'ner': 'O', 'lemma': 'happen', 'after': '', 'characterOffsetEnd': 28, 'index': 4, 'characterOffsetBegin': 20, 'pos': 'VBD'}, 
{'word': '.', 'before': '', 'originalText': '.', 'ner': 'O', 'lemma': '.', 'after': '', 'characterOffsetEnd': 29, 'index': 5, 'characterOffsetBegin': 28, 'pos': '.'}
]
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325657/why-does-normalizedner-for-dates-in-my-local-standford-corenlp-server-doesnt-di) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you closely look at the request made to corenlp server in the interactive demo, then you will see that current date is also sent as "date" parameter with the request. 
For eg. If your sentence is "I went to school today.", then "today" has normalized ner is "2017-19-09" (current date).
If you dont pass the "date" parameter, "today" won't have the exact date as normalized ner.

Hope it makes sense.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have added a new feature to allow you to tell the pipeline to use the present date as the `docDate` when running, this is the main source of your issue.  To get this feature you will have to use the latest version of Stanford CoreNLP available on GitHub.

Also, when you start the server you will have to use the `-serverProperties` option and supply a `.properties` file with these properties:

```
annotators = tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,entitymentions
ner.usePresentDateForDocDate = true
```

If you do this it should work now and properly list `2016`

Comment: Thanks! I will try this. Some of the sentences I am parsing were spoken at a past date, is there a way to pick different present dates for different sentences?

Comment: This does not seem to solve the problem that I get THIS P1Y OFFSET P-1Y in the normalizedNER field in the API response